# Sencha Touch form.setRecord() doesn't populate data to form

Tags: extjs, touch

I use list in mainview and when user click on item I display a form with textfields with extra data feilds.

my form has 3 textfields where the 'name' properties exactly as the field name in my model

so on list tap is use this code:

```
  var mainView = this.getMainView();
  var frmDetails = Ext.create('widget.frmDetails');
  frmDetails.setRecord(record);
  mainView.push(frmDetails);
```

But when my frmDetails displayed the textfields are empty !!

I checked that the name=fieldname, also id=fieldname

I suppose it will be easy using setRecord>

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

After 4 hours I found the solution and it was simple:

**Use Form.panel NOT panel**

[Found it here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?246463-Problem-setting-record-to-panel-from-controller](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?246463-Problem-setting-record-to-panel-from-controller)